# Difference between addthis_toolbox, addthis_sharing_toolbox, addthis_inline_share_toolbox?

Tags: addthis

I want to share url, title, image and description using add this social sharing buttons.

Also note that I have more than one addthis sharing buttons present on single page.

Comment: https://www.addthis.com/academy/setting-the-url-title-to-share/